# Connecting existing contribution to pledge

Tags: contributions, pledges

This Sunday was the first day for our church to receive payments in a financial campaign we are running. Some people have made pledges, and we have used CiviPledge to record those pledges.

I was under the assumption that when we recorded the donations to the same financial type as the pledge that CiviPledge would automatically figure out that that gift should count as a pledge payment.

However, it did not. I have since discovered the "Pledge" tab on an individual contact page which allows me to record a pledge payment, but that adds a completely different workflow to our record keeping.

Therefore, I have two related questions:

- Is there some way to connect a contribution to a pledge when the contribution is entered using the standard contribution entry form?
- How can I connect an existing contribution to a pledge after the contribution has been entered? (I am comfortable using the CiviCRM API, but have never programmed for the pledge component before.)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Getting a contribution that needs to be assigned to a pledge seems like a common use case. Did you build an extension for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, different workflow. with pledges, you create "expected" contributions for each time the donor said she'd contribute. You can then alter them via the api (eg with the api explorer)

The entity you want to change is pledgePayment. you can update the contribution_id, the amount and the status and it should then be working as expected

```
"values":[{
    "id":"1",
    "pledge_id":"1",
    "contribution_id":"10",
    "scheduled_amount":"500.00",
    "actual_amount":"500.00",
    "currency":"USD",
    "scheduled_date":"2009-07-01 00:00:00",
    "reminder_count":"0",
    "status_id":"1"
},
```

Comment: @Jeff - you marked this answer as accepted - and someone else has a similar need here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/connecting-existing-contribution-to-pledge-without-development.  Is it possible that you could post your extension on github?

Comment: @Jeff - Please count me among those who would like an extension for this! Are you able to share? If not the complete extension, perhaps explain what you did?