# Connecting existing contribution to pledge WITHOUT Development

Tags: contributions, pledges, civipledge

When someone makes a pledge, they may use a different contribution page to fullfil that pledge.

I see an API question about assigning an existing contribution to a pledge here: [Connecting existing contribution to pledge](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/connecting-existing-contribution-to-pledge).

**Is it necessary to create an extension to assign an existing contribution to fulfill a pledge**?  Perhaps this is a feature request to add an "assign to pledge" section on the contribution edit form.

Comment: It looks like Jeff Mikels (http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/331/jeff-mikels) must have either written an extension or given up on this function. I would love to be able to use this function as well. If you write an extension, would you be willing to share via github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this currently requires writing an extension (or submitting the code as a patch to be included in the core).