# Having trouble with pledges

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, contribution-page, pledges, civipledge

I have users with pledges set up for the total amount they have agreed to pay this year. They make payments on these pledges via contribution pages. The payments are not being matched to the pledge however, because the pages are not properly configured. However, every time I set a contribution page to accept pledges (in the "amounts" setting tab), it reverts back to not accepting pledges after the "save." Has anyone else encountered this bug? Do you know what I could do to circumvent it?

I would just go and apply the payments to the pledges manually, but apparently that is not possible either, without an extension. [Connecting existing contribution to pledge](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/connecting-existing-contribution-to-pledge) If you have an extension you are willing to share, that would be amazing.

Comment: What is your civicrm version? And could you see if could replicate this bug in the demo site? If so you could report a bug in https://issues.civicrm.org

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I'd like to work on fixing this again. How would I go about replicating/documenting the bug on the demo site? If you'd point me to some instructions, that would be awesome.

Comment: Well you test whether you have the same issue on the demo site (which is http://demo.civicrm.org) if so then you can file a bug report at https://issues.civicrm.org where you explain what the bug is, how the solution would look like and how you could reproduce the bug

Comment: Thanks, done! https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now reported this bug here; https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17651

The bug only shows up when using price fields for a contribution page. There are good reasons for using price sets, however, and there is no reason I can see not to allow pledges when using the price set functionality.

If you have any fixes or workarounds that allow me to still use the price sets, please let me know!